# No code input window in Netbeans 8 for Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to learn Java using the Netbeans 8.0 IDE.

On creating a new project and .java file, instead of getting a main code input window, the main window (where the start page tab is on 1st launching netbeans), shows a checked history button, and compare mode, but nowhere to input code.

I have looked at videos, and followed the exact same few simple steps that they did, but of the code template they get, instead I get this "history" tab, and nowhere to input code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't have a button right next to it that says *Source*? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Have you tried going to `Window | Editor` or event `Window | Reset Windows`

Comment: I had the same issues and none of the solutions mentioned so far has worked. I will include a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

From top text menu select "Window" then "Reset Window" and then restart NetBeans.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `userdir`.

From [the wiki at netbeans.org](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir):

> The NetBeans userdir is a directory where NetBeans stores user configuration data such as window layouts, editor settings, menu and toolbar customizations and various module settings.
>
> By default on Windows and Mac OS X the userdir is inside a directory NetBeans in application settings folder.

On Windows this can be found at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\`

On OS X this can be found at `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/`

See a related questions [here](https://forums.netbeans.org/topic59936.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44953723/1376127).

Answer (score 0):

`Window | Reset Windows` from main menu can give you back default layout with editor displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted Userdirectory of Netbeans8.2 IDE and Cache.
You can find these directories in ->Help-> abut tab of IDE.
After deleting these directories I reopened IDE it worked fine.

[image: Find directories in image]

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem today.  I was able to fix this it be clearing the NetBeans cache.

1) Delete all files under C:\Users\"user name"\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\

2) delete all files under C:\Users\"user name"\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\

3) If you have a bunch of saved projects under your user directory, e.g. C:\Users\"user name"\Documents\NetBeansProjects rename it.

C:\Users\"user name"\Documents\NetBeansProjects_save

You can copy them back when  netbeans is working properly again.

Answer (score -1):

You need to right-click on file -> editors -> source

Comment: it would be great if you can add screen shots of these!! It will help others to quickly locate what you are saying in your Answer