# When I open Netbeans and start a program, it won't let me input any code into the terminal

Tags: java, netbeans

This is a little bit puzzling to me, although this could just be a rookie mistake I'm making. I'm experienced with Python, though I was trying to go ahead and start working with Java via NetBeans. Unlike Python, which had a simple IDE to work with, I can't quite get NetBeans to even start allowing me to put code into the terminal. Here's where I'm at so far.

[image: NetBeans not loading the complier]

I've tried uninstalling and downloading the NetBeans IDE, but I seem to have this exact same problem. Does anybody have any idea how to work around this? This is a little bit frustrating, and I thought I would be having difficulty with the syntax, not the complier itself.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546868/no-code-input-window-in-netbeans-8-for-java?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, I can see that's its related. Doesn't look like it was ever resolved though.

Comment: Go to Tools -> Options -> Java; check all the settings. Also particularly the editor setting.

Comment: I checked the settings, and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it that I can see. Am I looking for something in particular in the editor setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `userdir`.

From [the wiki at netbeans.org](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir):

> The NetBeans userdir is a directory where NetBeans stores user configuration data such as window layouts, editor settings, menu and toolbar customizations and various module settings.
>
> By default on Windows and Mac OS X the userdir is inside a directory NetBeans in application settings folder.

On Windows this can be found at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\`

On OS X this can be found at `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/`

See a related question [here](https://forums.netbeans.org/topic59936.html).

Comment: Do you have a screenshot as to how you precisely delete the userdir? I've followed your directions, and now I don't know which files to delete. Do I delete all of them simultaneously, or just a select few?

Comment: @jayfeather31 Presumably navigate to the directory in File Explorer (Windows) or Finder (OS X) and delete all of the contents. Removing all of the folder contents will force NetBeans to regenerate it and hopefully solve your problem.